# Jackson represent Java String as Json numbers or Strings

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson2

I have the following java class, say for example Employee

```
class Employee{
      String empId; 
}
```

When I serialize this java class using Jackson Object Mapper, I get the sample Json output as, if the employee id is 123.

```
{
 "empId":"123"
}
```

What I would need is the below output if the emp Id is purely a number say for example 123

```
{
 "empId":123
}
```

And, if the employee Id is "A123"

```
{
 "empId":"A123"
}
```

I can write a custom Serializer class and annotate the empId with the custom Serializer but doing this on a large code base with many objects is a tedious process.

Does Jackson comes with any out of the box features to check if the String is a number, then represent it as number or else represent it as String during serialization process, something similar to Write Numbers as Strings feature

Do let me know your suggestions.

Comment: why not just handle this special case on your client? rather than doing a lot of work on the server?

Comment: sorry, that cannot be done on the client side. That's the reason why we are trying to do it on the server.

Comment: but what is the reason, use-case, that you need 2 different data types?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong in basics.

You try go against principals for data types.

How do you think any client can distinguish value type of field "empId"?

it **must** have one type - String or Number. Period.

Otherwise it is big pain in the ass for client side parsers. Same JSON structure cannot be parsed when for one instance same field is a String and for other it is a Number.

Comment: The consumers are already consuming legacy services. For the case I mentioned above, consumers may just use string and there ends the problem for this case. But if I have String return type for fields and the value that populates in the string return type is a number then the legacy services had a feature(bug) to  detect whether it is a string or number. Some consumers consuming this services may use this value as String and few others might have used this as number. I don't want to break either of the consumers because of this feature (bug) in legacy services.

Comment: Very bad approach... Anyway no any public tools can perform something against specifications to satisfy any possible bugs, mistakes, and bad designs, people can make.

Comment: agree with your comments